# Is it possible to PXE boot a Surface Pro, but deploy image via wireless?

Tags: windows-8, pxe, microsoft-surface-pro

We are working on imaging Surface Pro tablets, without using a Windows Deployment Server. Currently, we have Debian Linux running tftpd for booting other systems running Windows 7 for imaging.

With the Surface Pro tablets, we can boot off of a USB stick, but from there, **is there any way to have the Windows PE environment connect via Wifi to our network, and pull the image from the server over that?** The reason, you may ask? Cost of the adapters for PXE booting the Surfaces. We (the techs) can't warrant buying lots of them at this time. But we (as a company) can warrant the staff buying the tablets without discussing the implications with us (the techs).

We have successfully booted a Clonezilla environment and a Windows PE when booting from a USB drive plugged into a USB3 hub. Our goal is to load the Windows PE (or Clonezilla) into memory so we can remove the hub, and have it continue wirelessly while we boot off the same USB drive on another tablet. So, **is this possible?**

Comment: "But we (as a company) can warrant the staff buying the tablets without discussing the implications with us (the techs)." This made me laugh, and then cry. I know the feels. Best of luck to you.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I appreciate that. We've wasted lots of time on it, and our IT manager is trying to relay that message to those who keep asking for these devices, that we need more time and money before we can support it like Windows 7 and regular laptops/desktops. Oh well..